# Define $g(x)=\log_b(x)$ for $b>0$ in terms of the exponential function $f(x)=b^x$.

Tags: logarithms

I know that these two functions are inverses of each other, therefore how can you define one in terms of its inverse?

Comment: $g(x) = f(x)^{-1}$?

Comment: or $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$, for all $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x): (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto \log_b{x}$. Then, $f^{-1}(x):\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty):x \mapsto b^x$, with the relationship that $$f \circ f^{-1} = f(f^{-1}(x)) = x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1} \circ f .$$